# How to get exact date using ActionSheetDatePicker?

Tags: ios, swift, datepicker, uidatepicker, uiactionsheet

Here am trying to pick some date from date picker.

suppose i picked **2018-02-05** from action sheet. but in output am getting **2018-02-04**.

here is the following code i tried. In `print(value)`, i got following output

**Output**:2018-02-04 18:30:00 +0000

```
func dateAndTimePicker(_ sender: Any){
        let datePicker = ActionSheetDatePicker(title: "Date", datePickerMode: UIDatePickerMode.date, selectedDate: NSDate() as Date!, doneBlock: {
            picker, value, index in
            print(value) 

            return
        }, cancel: { ActionStringCancelBlock in return }, origin: (sender as AnyObject).superview!?.superview)
        datePicker?.show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Date pickers return a complete date and time. If your date picker only displays dates, then it always uses a time of 0:00. And `Date` does not have a time zone, so the date you get is always 0:00 UTC, not 0:00 in your local time zone. What you're getting is correct, because if you adjust that `Date` to be the time in your local time zone, it's 2018-02-05.

It's always good practice for apps to use UTC time internally and format dates for local time when showing dates and times to users. That way if someone travels to a different time zone, the data is still correct for their new location. You do this using `DateFormatter`. A simple example would be something like

```
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .short
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    let localDateString = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
```

Comment: It would help if you described how, specifically, this did not work.